# Are pendulum system ODEs stiff?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm interested in writing a numerical integrator to solve the motion of systems of pendulums.  For example, a simple case would be the [double pendulum](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/DoublePendulum.html).  The motion can be quite complex in general.

Is there a way to determine if a system of pendulums is going to produce stiff DEs before actually trying to integrate them?  Usually the masses and lengths of the pendulums are considered to be identical for the classic double pendulum system, which I suspect makes the system quite tame.  But I have nothing to back that up.